# Failed to load jupyterlab-git server extension

Tags: git, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am trying to install git extension in jupyterlab but I get error as below. All server extensions are enabled but it doesn't load.

[image]

```
(base) [root@user01 opt]# jupyter serverextension list
config dir: /opt/anaconda3/etc/jupyter
    jupyterlab  enabled
    - Validating...
      jupyterlab 2.2.6 OK
    jupyterlab_git  enabled
    - Validating...
      jupyterlab_git 0.23.3 OK
    nbdime  enabled
    - Validating...
      nbdime 2.1.0 OK
```

As suggested in another page I have installed `jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` but still that didn't help. I am running jupyterlab from jupyterhub on linux machine.

Comment: What is your `git --version`?

Comment: git version is 2.23.3

Comment: Is the output of the command exactly equal to `git version 2.23.3` or does it differ?

Comment: uninstalled everything and redone and the extension is working fine now but `Git Clone` button is greyed out in File explorer. Any idea on this @krassowski ?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/issues/809? It seems to have been fixed in master, so should be work fine once the new version for JupyterLab 3.0 gets released in the coming days.

Comment: The comments there say that a browser refresh may help.

Comment: I am surprised that issue didn't show up in google for me while searching. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/issues/809) introduced in jupyterlab-git 0.22.2. The comments in the GitHub issue mention that refreshing browser may help but I have not tried it. This issue was fixed in the new version for JupyterLab 3.0- you can install it with:

```
pip install jupyterlab==3
pip install jupyterlab-git==0.30
```

If you cannot yet update to JupyterLab 3.x, you can downgrade to 0.22.1 which is not affected:

```
pip install jupyterlab-git==0.22.1
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it with updating git on my Windows machine, and then updating jupyterlab-git.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know if it’s an option for many people, but I was having this issue, and it helped me to restart the Jupyter server (to restart the OS).

Comment: That did the trick for me. I installed the extension, ran the rebuild command and the error being thrown read "Failed to load the jupyterlab-git server extension..." together with instructions to ensure it's installed and check that it's enabled, which it was. I was able to fix it by restarting the server on which the jupyter lab was hosted.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/issues/861

The link above says that some people are getting this error because a new version of the extension has not been released for JL3.

So install the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Add below git binary file locations to PATH environment variable:

> 1. %PROGRAMFILES%\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
> 2. %PROGRAMFILES%\Git\usr\bin

and then restart the Jupyter session.