# jupyterlab-git extension cannot be found

Tags: jupyter-lab, elyra

Hi I have set up up a Jupyterlab with several extensions, among them the jupyterlab-git extension.
when I run

```
jupyter labextension list
```

I get:

```
JupyterLab v2.2.9
Known labextensions:
app dir: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\datamesh\share\jupyter\lab
    @elyra/code-snippet-extension v1.5.3 enabled  ok
    @elyra/metadata-extension v1.5.3 enabled  ok
    @elyra/pipeline-editor-extension v1.5.3 enabled  ok
    @elyra/python-editor-extension v1.5.3 enabled  ok
    @elyra/theme-extension v1.5.3 enabled  ok
    @jupyterlab/git v0.23.1 enabled  ok
    @jupyterlab/toc v4.0.0 enabled  ok
    jupyterlab_filetree v0.2.2 enabled  ok
    nbdime-jupyterlab v2.0.1 enabled  ok
```

the same here

```
jupyter serverextension list
```

I get:

```
config dir: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\datamesh\etc\jupyter
elyra enabled
- Validating...
  elyra 1.5.3 ok
jupyterlab enabled
- Validating...
  jupyterlab 2.2.9 ok
jupyterlab_git enabled
- Validating...
  jupyterlab_git 0.23.1 ok
nbdime enabled
- Validating...
  nbdime 2.1.0 ok
nbresuse enabled
- Validating...
  nbresuse  ok
```

But when I launch jupyterlab I get this:

```
Failed to load the jupyterlab-git server extension
git command not found - please ensure you have Git > 2 installed
```

of course is git installed!

How can fix this? I have searched high and low but couldn't find a fix.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65956578/6646912

Answer (score 2):

Just found out what the error was, may be someone has the same problem, so I share my findings here:

I have installed Git to use it with Git Bash only, so the PATH was not available for the jupyterlab-git extension to find.

Once I rerun the installation like described here

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-git-windows

all worked well.

A